# Laravel Eloquent get result where relation data is null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two Models `User` and `Owner` with many to many relationship

I want to fetch only those users who don't have owner

how can I get using eloquent

i tried

```
$query = User::whereHas('userOwners', function ( $subquery ){
                $subquery->whereNull('owner_id');                            
            })->get();
```

but not working.

Comment: @onlineThomas This is project management website where user(type1) assign project to user(type2) for followup.each user(type2) must have project, so need to find user who don't have any project. (Project is nothing its information of actual project owner(owners contact info for followup), )

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Eloquent has a way to query an absent relationships, it should work like this in your case:

```
$query = User::doesntHave('userOwners')->get();
```

Comment: Its Worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 User::with('userOwners')
        ->whereHas('userOwners', function ($query) {
            $query->wherehas('owner_id');
        })
        ->where('user_status', 1)->get();
```

use second where if you want to filter on user

use first where if you want to filter on Owner

Answer (score -4):

I think you should just change your query like:

```
$query = User::whereHas('userOwners')->get();
```

Hope this work for you!!!

Comment: He's asking for the opposite, users that do not have owners

Comment: This returning users with owner but I want without owners

Comment: @SharadKale Ok let me check